# Function output into loop

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops

I am trying to replicate the following code which work smoothly and add a parameter for date to the function and run the function with different date in a loop:

FUNCTION　V1:

```
def getOHLCV(currencies):
    c_price = []
    data = {}
    try:
        url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/historical'
        parameters = {
          'symbol': ",".join(currencies),
          #'time_start': ",".join(start_dates),
          'count':'91',
          'interval':'daily',
          'convert':'JPY',
        }
        headers = {
         'Accepts': 'application/json',
          'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        }
        session = Session()
        session.headers.update(headers)
        response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for currency in  data['data']:
            used_list = [
                item['quote']['JPY']
                for item in data['data'][currency]['quotes']
            ]
            price = pd.DataFrame.from_records(used_list)
            price['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(price['timestamp'])
            price['timestamp'] = price['timestamp'].astype(str).str[:-15]
            price_c = price.set_index('timestamp').close
            c_price.append(price_c.rename(currency))
    except Exception as e:
        print (data)
    return c_price

c_price = []
c_price.extend(getOHLCV(available[:61]))
c_price.extend(getOHLCV(available[61:]))
c_price = pd.concat(c_price, axis=1, sort=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 200)
c_price = c_price.transpose()
c_price.index.name = 'currency'
c_price.sort_index(axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

OUTPUT:

```
         2019-07-25   2019-07-26   2019-07-27   2019-07-28   2019-07-29  \
currency                                                                    
1WO          2.604104     2.502526     2.392313     2.418967     2.517868   
ABX          1.015568     0.957774     0.913224     0.922612     1.037273   
ADH          0.244782     0.282976     0.309931     0.287933     0.309613   
...               ...          ...          ...          ...          ...   
XTX          0.156103     0.156009     0.156009     0.165103     0.156498   
ZCO          0.685255     0.661324     0.703521     0.654763     0.616204   
ZPR          0.214395     0.204968     0.181529     0.178460     0.177596
```

FUNCTION　V2:

The V2 function add a parameter `start_dates` and loop the function with this new parameter. The issue is I got an empty dataframe from it. I assume that there is an issue with the date but I don't know where. Any help is appreciated.

```
def getOHLCV(currencies, start_dates):
    ...
          'symbol': ",".join(currencies),
          'time_start': ",".join(start_dates),
          ...

date_list = [(date.today() - timedelta(days= x * 91)) for x in range(3)][1:]
one = []
for i in date_list:
  c_price = []
  c_price.extend(getOHLCV(available[:61], i))
  c_price.extend(getOHLCV(available[61:], i))
c_price = pd.concat(c_price, axis=1, sort=True)
one = pd.concat(c_price, axis=1, sort=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array you are extending you are clearing at each iteration of the foor loop, it can be fixed like so

```py
date_list = [(date.today() - timedelta(days= x * 91)) for x in range(3)][1:]
one = []

c_price = []

for i in date_list:
  c_price.extend(getOHLCV(available[:61], i))
  c_price.extend(getOHLCV(available[61:], i))
c_price = pd.concat(c_price, axis=1, sort=True)
one = pd.concat(c_price, axis=1, sort=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 200)
```

Hope that works for you

**EDIT 1**

So we need to fix the error : `"time_start" must be a valid ISO 8601 timestamp or unix time value'`

This is because the return from this

```py
 date_list = [(date.today() - timedelta(days= x * 91)) for x in range(3)][1:]
```

Is this

```
[datetime.date(2019, 7, 24), datetime.date(2019, 4, 24)]
```

So we need to convert the list from datetime objects to something that the API will understand, we can do it the following way

```py
date_list = list(map(date.isoformat, date_list))
```

And we get the following output

```
['2019-07-24', '2019-04-24']
```

**Edit 2**

The error happens when we try to call join on something that isnt a list, so we can fix it by doing

```py
'time_start': start_dates
```

Instead of doing

```py
'time_start': ",".join(start_dates),
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inv_pos_aggregate.py", line 334, in <module>
    c_price = pd.concat(c_price, axis=1, sort=True)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 255, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 304, in __init__
    raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate`

Comment: Can i get you to print the contents of c_price for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: {}
{}
[]
{}
{}
[]

Comment: So the function does not return anything, since you only changed the parameters for the API it would seem that it doesnt return the correct thing. Do you get the correct response from the API In the function call?

Comment: @Shadefear I have the following message from the API but could not convert to the right format `"time_start" must be a valid ISO 8601 timestamp or unix time value',`

Comment: @Shadefear Thank you. I have the good output for the date but the API still gives me the same error message. `{'status': {'timestamp': '2019-10-23T08:58:47.786Z', 'error_code': 400, 'error_message': '"time_start" must be a valid ISO 8601 timestamp or unix time value', 'elapsed': 0, 'credit_count': 0, 'notice': None}}
{'status': {'timestamp': '2019-10-23T08:58:48.211Z', 'error_code': 400, 'error_message': '"time_start" must be a valid ISO 8601 timestamp or unix time value', 'elapsed': 0, 'credit_count': 0, 'notice': None}}
`

Comment: I think there is an error that you are parsing a single date from date_list to the function then you run ",".join on that single value. Try write it like so 'time_start': start_dates

Comment: Wooo, the error was there. I was not suspecting that. Should you change your answer so that I accept it? Thanks again